Multiplication concept with numbers that have fractional part
If multiplication is repeated addition, e.g. $5 \times 3 = 5 + 5 + 5$, what happens when $2$ factors are decimal numbers, e.g. $0.58 \times 0.49$?
What is the equivalent in repeated addition?
Note: I'm a beginner in math.

You probably learned about rational numbers in elementary school. Is this the subject of your question?

Hi @Malady, I refered to any number with decimals

Decimal is Division By 10 , so , $0.58=58/100$ , $0.49=49/100$ , then Decimal Multiplication is repeated Addition with Division By 10 , so , $0.580.49=[58/100][49/100]=[5849]/[100100]$

Hi @Prem, so why division By 10 and in the example division By 100? Sorry I think forgot some concepts

We have to use a ten for every Decimal Digit : Single Digit $0.5=5/10$ : Double Digit $0.59=59/100$ : Triple Digit $0.597=597/1000$ : ETC.

I understand @Prem, if we convert decimals to fractions we can represent repeated additions since we have whole numbers above and below when multiplying fractions, correct?

Exactly ! !

Thanks @Prem, and thanks for helping me remember basic concepts :)
